# Why can't pages be categorized / tagged?

Tags: pages, taxonomy

I'm having a hard time understanding the design choice to not allow pages to be categorized / tagged. Why exactly is this and what issues enabling that functionality for pages could create?

Comment: I think the WP team just chose to provide a standard/build-in post type that can be categorized via taxonomy terms, which is `post` (assigned to the `category` taxonomy); and another post type that can be categorized hierarchically via parent-child relationship, which is `page` (not assigned to any taxonomies). And you can actually - via a plugin or custom code - assign categories (and custom taxonomies) to the `page` post type.

Comment: @SallyCJ Aha. So it's more of a "this is the base on which upon you can build", because, honestly, I see no real reason for why they'd force you onto this and rightfully so, they don't, since you can easily enable categories for pages.

Comment: What I really meant is, WP started with just Posts, no Pages, no custom post types. But [14 years ago](https://wordpress.org/news/2005/02/strayhorn/), they introduced Pages so that users can create "static" pages that don't/rarely change. So it's just an additional feature one can have in WP. And if you want, you can turn it off manually (disable the *post type*). But it doesn't mean WP is better off remove/without that feature. And have you read [this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/pages/) - it can help you understand what Pages are and are for.

Comment: @DanielSmith wouldn't it be great to post the answer for how to enable categories for pages here? I'm searching for it right now.